# Rails: rake db:migrate isn't output to script/server console window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rake

i have two cmd consoles opened in Windows. One is running the "ruby script/server" the other i run a "rake db:migrate" command. But the server console doesn't output the log of the migration? Someone has an idea what's the reason?

Comment: This is not how srcipt/server works. You are looking for running `tail -f log/development.log` in a third console and you will see all the output from anything run, whether console or rake or the server

Answer (score 0):

You just see this log in your log file. The server log only what happen in this thread, no in other.

Comment: Hello, i saw a tutorial where the log of rake db migrate was output to the consolewindows of script/server. unfortunatly i can't rember with video tutorial this was demonstrated. So i think this must be possible? Perhaps i have to do additional settings for this, anybody knows?